# Times the Markov chain hits a state and absorbing probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, birth-death-process

In the book adventures in stochastic process by Resnick define this :

${\tau}_{i}=inf\{n\ge 0:{X}_{n}=i\}$ and

${\tau}_{i}(n)=inf\{n>{\tau}_{i}(n-1):{X}_{n}=i\}$ assuming ${\tau}_{i}(n-1)<\infty$.

In a birth and death chain I would like compute :

${P}_{a}({\tau}_{a}(2)<{\tau}_{b})$ where $b$ is an absorbing state . I know how to compute ${P}_{c}({\tau}_{a}<{\tau}_{b})$ and I was thinking to proceed in the same way but I’m not sure.

Comment: How would you go about computing $\mathbb P(\tau_a<\tau_b\mid X_0=c)$?